# How to identify types in boost fusion vector

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

How would one go about identifying the types inside a boost::fusion vector?

e.g.

```
fusion::vector<int, double, string> v;
```

then something that would let me identify `v[0]` as being type `int`, `v[1]` as type `double` and `v[2]` as type `string`.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as `v[0]` as I remember, because you need a compile-time construct. What did you try and what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to extract an element from a `boost::fusion::vector` you need to use `boost::fusion::at_c`, like this:

```
boost::fusion::vector<int, std::string> v(1, "hello");
std::cout << boost::fusion::at_c<0>(v) << std::endl; // prints 1
```

The type at position N is:

```
boost::fusion::result_of::at_c<boost::fusion::vector<int, std::string>, 1>::type
```

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/metafunctions/value_at.html) describes what I was trying to do.

In detail, the following is what I was trying to achieve:

```
template<int N, typename T>
struct a_struct{
typedef typename T::value_type etype;
typedef typename boost::fusion::result_of::value_at<etype, boost::mpl::int_<N> >::type a_type;
};
```

Where T is a std::vector of boost::fusion vectors.